# How to set the field in a list as current user ID?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

I am creating a List where one of field is required to be the current logged in user ID, requirement is specified as the the column value should contains the current logged in User Id. I am new to SharePoint so any advice in details will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For that, there are two fields:

1. **Created By** - This field stores the user who has created/added the list item.
2. **Modified By** - This field stores the user who has modified/edited the list item. When a new list item is added/created, the user is same in 'Created By' and 'Modified By' fields.

Thus instead of using a new user field, you can use one of them which suits you best.